# How to navigate a few folders up?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

One option would be to do System.IO.Directory.GetParent() a few times. Is there a more graceful way of travelling a few folders up from where the executing assembly resides?

What I am trying to do is find a text file that resides one folder above the application folder. But the assembly itself is inside the bin, which is a few folders deep in the application folder.

Comment: usually a relative path does the trick like '..\..\..\..\Downfolder' but it depends on what exactly you're trying to do this for...?

Comment: is this always the case?

Comment: "Navigate" how?  Do you mean the current directory?  If so, you should be able to do `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"..\..\..\..");`

Answer (score 314):

Other simple way is to do this:

```
string path = @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4";
string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\..\"));
```

**Note** This goes two levels up. The result would be:
`newPath = @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\";`

**Additional Note**
`Path.GetFullPath` normalizes the final result based on what environment your code is running on windows/mac/mobile/...

Comment: There is no point using `Path.Combine` when you are adding backslash manually anyway. Consider using `Path.Combine(path, "..", "..")` instead.

Comment: @AXMIM using GetFullPath will return the absolute path, it makes a difference in most situation. Try entering the above code in CodeBunk and see the result would be different if not using GetFullPath, and in most cases might cause bugs.

Comment: Will that work for any OS or only for some specific that use backslash in paths, e.g., Windows?

Comment: @alcoholisevil I've tested in on Windows, not sure about Mac, I guess it should work on mac as well. (getFullPath should normalize path string for each environment/os)

Comment: You can also combine them (and would be better probably): `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, "..", ".."))`

Comment: This answer should be updated to the commented one using combine rather than the backslashes. The backslash one didn't work for me.

Answer (score 49):

if c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\bin is the path then the following code will return the path base folder of bin folder

```
//string directory=System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString());

string directory=System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString();
```

ie,c:\folder1\folder2\folder3

if you want folder2 path then you can get the directory by

```
string directory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString()).ToString();
```

then you will get path as c:\folder1\folder2\

Answer (score 14):

You can use `..\path` to go one level up, `..\..\path` to go two levels up from path.

You can use `Path` class too.

[C# Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

This is what worked best for me:

`string parentOfStartupPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"../"));`

Getting the 'right' path wasn't the problem, adding '../' obviously does that, but after that, the given string isn't usable, because it will just add the '../' at the end.
Surrounding it with `Path.GetFullPath()` will give you the absolute path, making it usable.

Comment: Thank you, weirdly the other solutions were not working for me but this did the trick

Answer (score 6):

The following method searches a file beginning with the application startup path (*.exe folder). If the file is not found there, the parent folders are searched until either the file is found or the root folder has been reached. `null` is returned if the file was not found.

```
public static FileInfo FindApplicationFile(string fileName)
{
    string startPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, fileName);
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(startPath);
    while (!file.Exists) {
        if (file.Directory.Parent == null) {
            return null;
        }
        DirectoryInfo parentDir = file.Directory.Parent;
        file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(parentDir.FullName, file.Name));
    }
    return file;
}
```

Note: `Application.StartupPath` is usually used in WinForms applications, but it works in console applications as well; however, you will have to set a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly. You can replace `Application.StartupPath` by
`Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` if you prefer.

I use this strategy to find configuration and resource files. This allows me to share them for multiple applications or for Debug and Release versions of an application by placing them in a common parent folder.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static string AppRootDirectory()
        {
            string _BaseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(_BaseDirectory, @"..\..\"));
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could use a function if you want to declare the number of levels and put it into a function?

```
private String GetParents(Int32 noOfLevels, String currentpath)
{
     String path = "";
     for(int i=0; i< noOfLevels; i++)
     {
         path += @"..\";
     }
     path += currentpath;
     return path;
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
String path = this.GetParents(4, currentpath);
```

Answer (score 5):

C#

```
string upTwoDir = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Hiding a looped call to Directory.GetParent(path) inside an static method is the way to go.

Messing around with ".." and Path.Combine will ultimately lead to bugs related to the operation system or simply fail due to mix up between relative paths and absolute paths.

```
public static class PathUtils
{
    public static string MoveUp(string path, int noOfLevels)
    {
        string parentPath = path.TrimEnd(new[] { '/', '\\' });
        for (int i=0; i< noOfLevels; i++)
        {
            parentPath = Directory.GetParent(parentPath ).ToString();
        }
        return parentPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this may help

```
string parentOfStartupPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"../../")) + "Orders.xml";
if (File.Exists(parentOfStartupPath))
{
    // file found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the folder you want to navigate to, find the index of it then substring.

```
            var ind = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString().IndexOf("Folderame");

            string productFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString().Substring(0, ind);
```

Comment: This fails in **so many** cases. What if the name of the folder is just `a`, for example? What if the path looks like this `C:\Folderame3\Folderame2\Folderame\...`?

Comment: if folder name is just a search "\\a\\" or \\a if its last

Answer (score 1):

I have some virtual directories and I cannot use Directory methods. So, I made a simple split/join function for those interested. Not as safe though.

```
var splitResult = filePath.Split(new[] {'/', '\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var newFilePath = Path.Combine(filePath.Take(splitResult.Length - 1).ToArray());
```

So, if you want to move 4 up, you just need to change the `1` to `4` and add some checks to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Path parsing via `System.IO.Directory.GetParent` is possible, but would require to run same function multiple times.

Slightly simpler approach is to threat path as a normal string, split it by path separator, take out what is not necessary and then recombine string back.

`var upperDir = String.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, dir.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).SkipLast(2));`

Of course you can replace `2` with amount of levels you need to jump up.

Notice also that this function call to `Path.GetFullPath` (other answers in here) will query whether path exists using file system. Using basic string operation does not require any file system operations.