# WPF Desktop App Get Path to Image at Run Time

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

.Net 4.5 WPF desktop application,
goal is to add an existing image to a pdfSharp doc. First step is getting the path to the image. My image is in an Images folder under my project. I've tried:

```
String myPath = string.Empty;
myPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
myPath = myPath + "\\Images\\MyImage.png";

myPath ends up being: 
C:\\Users\\My User Name\\Documents\\LocalProjects\\MyProject\\MyProject\\bin\\Debug\\Images\\MyImage.png
```

Then I check using File.Exists in an If statement. It fails.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the path incorrect? If so, what is the correct path?

Comment: I thought that would be correct, however it isn't as File.Exists returns false.

Comment: You may want to check the path of your image.

Comment: The none runtime path to my image is:C:\Users\My User Name\Documents\LocalProjects\MyProject\MyProject\Images\MyImage.png

Comment: path of your image is different than the value of the mypath... so it fails.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer in this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899422/how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up

Comment: Make sure that the `Build Action` of the image file in your project is set to `Content`, and set `Copy to Output Directory` to a value other than `Do not copy`.

Comment: @Clemens. That did it, thank you! How do I mark your comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `Build Action` of the image file in your project is set to `Content`, and set `Copy to Output Directory` to a value other than `Do not copy`.

Otherwise the image file (including its relative path) won't be copied to the output directory `bin\Debug\`.