# Moving up a folder from the executable

Tags: c#, directory

I am trying to make a file path inside of the folder above the executable. For instance, I am wanting the variable `TAGPATH` to be the filepath to an executable in the folder `C:\User\ApplicationFolder\tag_rw\tag_rw.exe` while the application is in `C:\User\ApplicationFolder\AppFiles`. I want the application to be portable, meaning no matter the folder names it will retrieve the filepath of the application's executable then go to the parent folder and navigate into `tag_rw\tag_rw.exe`.

I basically want `string TAGPATH = @"path_to_appfolder\\tag_rw\\tag_rw.exe"`

Here is what I have tired so far (using the first answer [How to navigate a few folders up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899422/how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up) ):

```
  string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
  string TAGPATH = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, @"..\"));
```

I am getting a run-time error `ArgumentException` with the description `URI formats are not supported.`

Is there an easier/better way to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: If i did not misunderstand your question, you simply want get **parent directory**?

Comment: Yes. Should have just said that instead of the long paragraph. It would also be nice to get the parent directory of the initial parent directory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cur = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        Console.WriteLine(cur);
        string parent1 = Path.Combine(cur, @"..\");
        Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(parent1).FullName);
        string parent2 = Path.Combine(cur, @"..\..\");
        Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(parent2).FullName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

Navigation is limited to absolute and relative types. I think you mean to navigate to parent directory regardless of whole application location.
Maybe you try relative path

```
string TAGPATH = "..\\tag_rw\\tagrw.exe"
```