# How to go one level higher in the file directory when reading a txt file in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a txt file located in the application folder, in visual studio i just write "File.read("doc.txt")", however i would like to place the txt file outside of the applications folder

e.g right now its located in
`c:\Desktop\Folder\application\doc.txt` and i want to place the `doc.txt` inside `c:\desktop\folder` and read it from there without specifying the exact path of the txt file as folder might be moved to another drive e.g inside D drive `D:\desktop\folder`

if the user moves the folder and my hard code is "file.read("C:\desktop\folder\doc.txt")" its going to throw an error, so how is there anyway to read a file that is one location above the applications main Folder?

Comment: Try this: `@"..\doc.txt"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate a few folders up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899422/how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks that worked can you post it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.Read(@"..\doc.txt");
```

Will achieve this, the reason to add @ at the start is to show that you're writing a string literal which will allow you to use '\' without needing to escape it. the ".." part is how you tell the document to go into the parent directory.

Comment: Hm what is the "\" used for actually if we cant write it in the string?

Comment: @guyguy, it's an escape character as well as a folder separator. Without the '@' you would need to write `"..\\doc.txt"`.

Comment: You can write it in a string but without the `@` in front of the string it has a special meaning, it "escapes" the next character, either adding or taking away meaning. For instance, `n` in a string is just the letter n, but if you write `\n`, it means *newline*, the two characters gets replaced by one. To actually write a backslash into a string, without using `@` in front of it you need to escape the backslash, so you would have to write `"..\\doc.txt"`.