# How to replace path directory starting with some word with another?

Tags: c#

I have got the path using the following:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

But the path I get is this:

```
C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Agent-127.0.0.1-3000\Better_Result\Check\Libraries\x64
```

I want to replace this `Agent-127.0.0.1-3000` with `Latest`. The Phrase `Agent-127.0.0.1-3000` is not fixed but it always starts with `Agent`.

Hence, please let me know what I can do.
The final output I want is:

```
C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Latest\Better_Result\Check\
```

I do not want Libraries\x64 also.
Please let me know.

Comment: `path = Regex.Replace(path, @"\bAgent-\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}-\d+\b", "Latest")`. And for the second requirement, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14899422/8967612) (or you can achieve it with substitution as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
var newPath= Regex.Replace(oldPath,@"(?<=\\)Agent[^\\]*","Latest");
```