# How to navigate a few folders up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

The exact same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899422/how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up) has been asked, but I don't understand why I am not receiving the same output.

I've tested it using the same [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPjuY.png) below (without full path)

```
string path = @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4";
string newPath = Path.Combine(path, @"..\..\");
```

Now from the original question that was asked. The answer was the result should be:

```
newPath = @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\";
```

However I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnW6f.png):

```
newPath = @"C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4/..\\..\\";
```

EDIT: Using the line below still did not accomplish what it was supposed to do.

```
Path.Combine(path, "..", "..");
```

output using above resulted below:

```
"C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4/../.."
```

Comment: Use `Path.Combine(path, "..", "..");` as explained in the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899422/how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up#comment97806320_30902714.

Comment: @Progman Thanks for the response. I've used `Path.Combine(path, "..", "..");` and I've gotten: `"C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4/../.."` as the value.

Comment: @Progman which did not behave how it should.

Comment: So what is wrong for it? This path points to a folder that you need. It will work for you. Or you need to output the path somewhere else in a handy format?

Comment: @Progman Sorry, your solution was correct. It was my transition from Windows to Mac. I didn't realize there was a path difference. Appreciate your help!