# Files not running from the directory chosen

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I run my program and it works fine. I am using external Batch and VBS files **however** if these files are not in my main C:\ Directory then it don't work at all! I get a cannot find file specified and so ****How** can I make sure that my files run in my directory that my program installs in every time** C:\Program Files (x86)\ then of course it makes a program folder.

[image: screenshot]

example of the code I used which I got from another forum on this site.

```
Process scriptProc = new Process();
            scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"Services.bat";
            scriptProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Buzzard X Soy Optimzation Program\"; //<---very important 
            scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "//B //Nologo Services.bat";
            scriptProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //prevent console window from popping up
            scriptProc.Start();
            scriptProc.WaitForExit();
            scriptProc.Close();
```

Comment: Are you running your code from `C:\>` directly? If so, then that is where `scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName` is looking, not other directories

Comment: no thats just for some reason where it works at

Comment: How are you running the code, though? From CMD?

Comment: Well Yes and No the buttons are compiled in VS but the Batch files runs through CMD yes. but for some reason it will only work if the files are directly in C: and C: only no sub folder I am also new to code and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=net-5.0) to get the directory from which your executeble was run, and [navigate to the desired folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899422/how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up) relative to your starting path.

You should virtually never put absolute paths in code, because of the exact problem you are encountering.

Comment: can i get a example of this if you don't mind? and how I can a apply it? I am new to C#

Comment: @Buzzard Sure. I can show you how to do it with your code specifically if you give me some input. Directly above the code you wrote write this `var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Put a breakpoint right after that and let me know what path is.

Comment: I did that and do you want me to run it?

Comment: it seems to may have worked actually.. let me build it rq if it did work though thanks alot

Comment: @Buzzard youre welcome.  If my answer solved the problem for you please upvote and select it as the best answer